# python Dictionary key value compare and store

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionary like :

```
A = {
    "Name": ["AAAAA"],
    "designation": ["DDDDDDD"],
    "doj": ["KKKKKK"],
    "RRRRRRRR": ["JJJJJJ"]
}



 B = {
        {
    u'IIIIII': u'200',
    u'KKKKKK': u'1/1/2015',
    u'JJJJJJ': u'legal',
    u'HHHHHH': u'John'
}{
    u'AAAAA': u'Stacie',
    u'DDDDDDD': u'6/8/2014',
    u'BBBB': u'2/9/1988',
    u'CCCCCCC': u'legal'
}
    }
```

I have to take the value of A and compare to key of B and if the name matches I should get the value of key from `B` and store. Something like

```
{
    "Name": ["John"],
    "designation": ["12/02/2016"],
    "doj":["Manager"]
}
```

I am trying to loop both and then trying to append value to a dict item using the get method but could not achieve the goal.

```
for key,value in content.iteritems():
    #print value    
    if isinstance(value, list):
        vals.append(key)
        for i in value:
            ii=0
            #while(ii<len(z)):  
            if (z.get(i)== 'true' ) :           
                vals.append(z.get(i))
```

Comment: Why are your values all lists with just one value in each? That makes things that little more complicated.

Comment: i am taking from a json and storing it in a list using list()

Comment: Sure, but *why*? What should happen if there is *more than one* element in each list in `A`? What should happen for more than one element in `B`?

Comment: In future, make your keys actually match. Not using repeated letters could help, use [metasyntactic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) like `foo`, `bar` and `spam` instead to avoid such problems.

Comment: It does have more than one element in the list.

Comment: @tec_abhi: in what list? What should happen in that case? And what should happen if only *some* items match?

Comment: Sorry , i think i am not much clear on my question. I am pulling out data from a db and storing it to a dict(). So here B is actually a list of dict() like below {
    u'IIIIII': u'200',
    u'KKKKKK': u'1/1/2015',
    u'JJJJJJ': u'legal',
    u'HHHHHH': u'John'
}{
    u'AAAAA': u'Stacie',
    u'DDDDDDD': u'6/8/2014',
    u'BBBB': u'2/9/1988',
    u'CCCCCCC': u'legal'
}...  So in here i have to compare the values and then store it. B has list of values corresponding to key which is actually value of A dict.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is considering the values of `A` and `B` provided in the question:

```
z = {}
for k, v in A.items():
    av = B.get(v[0], None)
    if av is not None:
        z[k] = av

print(z)
# {'Name': ['John'], 'designation': ['12/02/2016'], 'doj': ['Manager']}
```

or, a one liner:

```
z = {k: B[v[0]] for k, v in A.items() if v[0] in B}
# {'Name': ['John'], 'designation': ['12/02/2016'], 'doj': ['Manager']}
```

Comment: I've updated the question to at least make the expected output *possible*. The OP clearly miscounted their `A`s and `K`s when typing out their question, so your demo output may need updating. There are still huge question-marks around the use of lists however; what should happen when there is more than one element in `A[somekey]` for instance? What if some are in B but not all?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my output and I understand your reasoning completely. But, I still wonder why he has stored keys in list etc.